# CP-SAT's `NumBooleans()` parameter

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

The solver API for CP-SAT offers the attribute `NumBooleans`, which is documented as "Returns the number of boolean variables managed by the SAT solver".

Excuse my ignorance, but why is this a property of the *solution* rather than the model itself? Should I think about the solver as applying some simplifying preprocessing steps to the model, and the number indicating the complexity of the model after that, or what is the right mental model here?

Answer (score 5):

This does not count Boolean variables in the model. It counts Boolean variables in the SAT solver. This is vastly different. Presolve is happening, some constraints are expanded, search and conflicts create Boolean variables. It differs even among workers solving the same model.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like when creating statistics about the relation between problem size and solver time, NumBooleans would be a useful measure to take into account as well.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what is happening during presolve?

Comment: a bit complex. Presolve is 17k lines of code. Three things happen in presolve: (a) constraint simplification/rewriting, domain reduction, and constraint expansion. One particularity of CP-SAT is constraint expansion. A lot of CP constraints, and sometimes a linear constraints are expanded. Domains of integer variables can be rewritten as an array of Boolean variables. In all these cases, new Boolean variables are introduced.